# VBA/Macro Button

Tags: vba, excel, button

So I have a button to randomly pick a number from a range of 1 to 100 and place in a cell:

```
Public Sub RangeValue()
    Dim i As Long
    Static n As Long, s As String
    Const MIN = 1, MAX = 100, OUT = "L10", DEL = "."
    Randomize
    Do
        i = Rnd * (MAX - MIN) + MIN
        If 0 = InStr(s, i & DEL) Then
            n = n + 1: s = s & i & DEL
            Range(OUT) = i
            If n > MAX - MIN Then n = 0: s = ""
            Exit Do
        End If: DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

I want it to now pick 2 number from that range and place into two cells. I have tried:

```
Public Sub RangeValue()
    Dim i As Long
    Static n As Long, s As String
    Const MIN = 1, MAX = 100, OUT = "L10""L11", DEL = "."
    Randomize
    Do
        i = Rnd * (MAX - MIN) + MIN
        If 0 = InStr(s, i & DEL) Then
            n = n + 1: s = s & i & DEL
            Range(OUT) = i
            If n > MAX - MIN Then n = 0: s = ""
            Exit Do
        End If: DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

But it does not work. The goal is to have 2 numbers picked and put into 2 cells, and have them not repeat till all 100 numbers have been used.

Answer (score 0):

I have not looked at your code closely but for the same you can also try code like below which is simpler to maintain and shall give similar results.

```
    Sub RandomValues()
    With Range("L10:L11")
        .Formula = "=RANDBETWEEN(1,100)"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: It will repeat. I want it to go through all 100 numbers before it reuses a number

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Public arr(1 To 100) As Variant

Sub ButtonCode()
    If arr(1) = "" Then
        For I = 1 To 100
            arr(I) = I
        Next I
        Call Shuffle(arr)
        Range("L10").Value = arr(1)
    Else
        N = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(Range("L10:L" & Rows.Count))
        Range("L10").Offset(N) = arr(N + 1)
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub Shuffle(InOut() As Variant)
    Dim I As Long, J As Long
    Dim tempF As Double, Temp As Variant

    Hi = UBound(InOut)
    Low = LBound(InOut)
    ReDim Helper(Low To Hi) As Double
    Randomize

    For I = Low To Hi
        Helper(I) = Rnd
    Next I


    J = (Hi - Low + 1) \ 2
    Do While J > 0
        For I = Low To Hi - J
          If Helper(I) > Helper(I + J) Then
            tempF = Helper(I)
            Helper(I) = Helper(I + J)
            Helper(I + J) = tempF
            Temp = InOut(I)
            InOut(I) = InOut(I + J)
            InOut(I + J) = Temp
          End If
        Next I
        For I = Hi - J To Low Step -1
          If Helper(I) > Helper(I + J) Then
            tempF = Helper(I)
            Helper(I) = Helper(I + J)
            Helper(I + J) = tempF
            Temp = InOut(I)
            InOut(I) = InOut(I + J)
            InOut(I + J) = Temp
          End If
        Next I
        J = J \ 2
    Loop
End Sub
```

This code will add values to the list starting with cell **L10**, without repeats.

**EDIT#1:**

This should be better:

```
Dim arr(1 To 100) As Variant
Dim clicks As Integer

Sub ButtonCode2()
    If arr(1) = "" Then
        For I = 1 To 100
            arr(I) = I
        Next I

        Call Shuffle(arr)

        Range("L10").Value = arr(1)
        Range("L11").Value = arr(2)
        clicks = 3
    Else
        Range("L10").Value = arr(clicks)
        Range("L11").Value = arr(clicks + 1)
        clicks = clicks + 2
    End If
End Sub
```

*(leave the Shuffle code as is)*

Comment: It is giving me an error: Constants, fixed length strings, arrays, user defined tyoes not allowed as public members

Comment: @user8772722  Strange..................What happens if you use **Dim** in place of **Public** ??

Comment: That kindof worked. But my goal is to have 2 numbers from a range of 1-100 and display in cells L10 & L11. I need the numbers not to ever repeat or be the same. meaning, it would take 50 clicks of that button to go through all the numbers

Comment: I hope I understand.......you only want to fill ***2*** cells............. ***1*** click should fill both cells...............no repeats until all used up.......... **??**

Comment: Correct . I want all 100 numbers to be used before it will repeat

Comment: See my **EDIT#1:**

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so so so much